# How to replace set of characters inside string

Tags: javascript

i have a string where there is no space in between and there is a set of characters  which keeps on repeating in the same string, but i want to replace those set of characters with `\n`. here is what i have tried but i'm not able to see anything

here is the string

```
lorem%20ipsum%20skdjajsadsa%0D%0Askdjsadkasjdkjasdsjds%0D%0Aadasdkjsadkjsad%0D%0Aaki7yuj%0
```

in the string there are 3 occurrences of  `%0D%0A`, i want to replace those with `\n`, how can i do this

here is what i have tried.

```js
str = "lorem%20ipsum%20skdjajsadsa%0D%0Askdjsadkasjdkjasdsjds%0D%0Aadasdkjsadkjsad%0D%0Aaki7yuj%0"

console.log(
  str.replace("%0D%0A", "\n")
);
```

Comment: 1. You need to save the result, i.e. `str = str.replace("....");` 2. use the [`g` global modifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Syntax) 3. console.log the result, the \n is just a space if you show it in an html container

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx with the global flag [`g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) to remove all occurrences:

```js
var str = "lorem%20ipsum%20skdjajsadsa%0D%0Askdjsadkasjdkjasdsjds%0D%0Aadasdkjsadkjsad%0D%0Aaki7yuj%0"

str = str.replace(/%0D%0A/g, "\n");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Really? Answering this instead of marking it a typo or close as dupe?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```js
let str = "lorem%20ipsum%20skdjajsadsa%0D%0Askdjsadkasjdkjasdsjds%0D%0Aadasdkjsadkjsad%0D%0Aaki7yuj%0"

let r= str.replace(/(%0D%0A)/g,"\n");

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Really? Answering this instead of marking it a typo or close as dupe?